# Show that every number in $[\frac{1}{2},1)$ is in a unique interval $[\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n+1}{n+2}]$.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that every number in $[\frac{1}{2},1)$ is in a unique interval $[\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n+1}{n+2}]$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Intuitively, I think this is correct, but I do not know how to write a rigorous proof. More generally, given a covergent sequence $(x_n)$ with each $x_n$ in some interval $[a,b)$ ($b$ is the limit of this sequence), is there a universal approach to show that each element of $[a,b)$ is in some unique interval $[x_n,x_{n+1}]$?

Comment: Well, it won't be true for any of the boundary points.  For instance, $\frac 2 3$ will be in both the one where it is an upper bound and a lower bound.  Besides for those,  it's true because you have an increasing sequence of boundary points. As far as the general question, it'll be true if the sequence is monotone,  otherwise weird things can happen

Comment: You need to exclude one of the bounds of each interval of the family.

Comment: @Alan You are correct. How about this: Show that every number in $[\frac{1}{2},1)$ is in a unique interval $[\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n+1}{n+2})$. May you elaborate on why the fact that it is an increasing sequence is important and give me more suggestions/hints about writing a rigorous proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean $[\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n+1}{n+2})$?

So you want to prove there is unique $n$ such that $${n\over n+1}\leq x<{n+1\over n+2}$$ which is equivalent to $${2x-1\over 1-x}< n\leq {x\over 1-x}$$ Since

$$ {x\over 1-x}-{2x-1\over 1-x}=1$$ we are done.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use monotonicity, i.e.
$$x_0 \le \dots \le x_n \le x_{n+1} \le \dots \le x_\infty,$$

where $x_\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$.

##### In at most one interval

Assume the opposite, i.e. that some number $x$ is in two intervals i.e. $x\in [x_n, x_{n+1})$ and $x\in[x_{n+m}, x_{n+m+1})$.

Can you deduce a contradiction yourself?

> We have $x_{n+m} \le x<x_{n+1} \le x_{n+m}$ where the last inequality is due to monotonicity. But since there is a strict inequality in there, we have $x_{n+m} \neq x_{n+m}$ which is a contradiction

##### In at least one interval

We want to show that any $x\in [x_0, x_\infty)$ is included in *some* interval $[x_n, x_{n+1})$. Here you want to use that a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) is a [connected relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_relation). I.e. we have either
$x_n \le x$ or $x\le x_n$. Additionally we know that $0<x_\infty-x$.

> Define $\epsilon := x_\infty - x >0$. Due to convergence of the $x_n$ we have some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_\infty - x_n < \epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. This implies $x < x_n$ for all $n\ge N$. Due to connectedness, there is a *first* $x_{N_0}$ in $x_0,\dots, x_N$ such that $x < x_{N_0}$. All previous $x_n$ are smaller. Therefore $$x\in [x_{N_0-1}, x_{N_0})$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_n:=\left[ \frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)$.
We have $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k\right)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{n+1}{n+2} \right)=\left[ \frac{1}{2},1\right)   $.

 Thus,every point in $[0,1)$ belongs to at least one interval of form $\left[ \frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)$. On the other hand, $A_m \cap A_n = \emptyset$ for all $m \ne n$.Therefore each point $\left[ \frac{1}{2},1\right)$ cannot belong to two different sets of form $\left[ \frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)$. Hence the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is very simple. All we need to prove is that

$\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty }[\dfrac{k}{k+1},\dfrac{k+1}{k+2})=[\dfrac{1}{2}, 1)$. It is clear that

$\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty }[\dfrac{k}{k+1},\dfrac{k+1}{k+2})\subseteq [\dfrac{1}{2}, 1)$ since

every interval of the union is a subset of $[\dfrac{1}{2},1)$. Now we will prove that

$[\dfrac{1}{2}, 1)\subseteq\,\,\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty }[\dfrac{k}{k+1},\dfrac{k+1}{k+2})$.

Assume that there is an $a$ in $[\dfrac{1}{2},1)$ but not in the union. Then

$a\,\notin \,\,\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}[\dfrac{k}{k+1},\dfrac{k+1}{k+2})$  for all $n$, therefore $a\geq \dfrac{n+1}{n+2}$ for all $n$ and

taking the limit of the sequence $a\,\geq \,1$ which is a contradiction because $a$ is in $[\dfrac{1}{2},1)$ !!

Comment: You should either use `\frac {k}{k+1}` to get $\frac { k }{ k+1 }$, or use parentheses like $k/(k+1)$ since $k/k+1 = 1 + 1 = 2$, by the usual conventions.

Comment: The trouble with fractions is that come out very small, that is why I am using parentheses! You are right, thanks!

Comment: Understandable. Here are some alternatives `$\displaystyle \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty }\left[\frac{k}{k+1},\frac{k+1}{k+2} \right)=\left[\frac 12, 1 \right)$` or `$$\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty }\left[\frac{k}{k+1},\frac{k+1}{k+2} \right)=\left[\frac 12, 1 \right)$$`. You can also just use `$\dfrac{k}{k+1}$`. Observe the `\left( ... \right)` syntax to get your parentheses to be of appropriate size.

Comment: Many thanks! I agree that parentheses are very  awkward to the reader! Excellent! It works!